# Method of characteristics for $wl_x + xl_w + (x+y)l_z = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

$$w\partial_xl + x\partial_wl+(x+w)\partial_zl  = 0;$$ $$ l = l(x, w) , \quad x + w > 0.$$

I was solving this question but I got stuck.
After dividing by $x+y $,
I get that $s = z$ and 
had $$ C_1=\tfrac12 x^2+zx-yz ,$$
$$C_2=\tfrac12 y^2 +yz-zx  $$
but when verifying, I didn't get the right answer so can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

$$y\partial_xu + x\partial_yu+(x+y)\partial_zu  = 0;$$
Solving with method of characteristics:

Since $x+y \ne 0$ :
$$\frac {dx}{y}=\frac {dy}{x}=\frac {dz}{x+y}=\frac {du} 0$$
The first integral curve is easy to find:
$$du=0 \implies c_0=u$$
$$  \frac {d(x+y)}{x+y}=\frac {dz}{x+y}$$
$$\implies c_1=x+y-z$$
Is an integral curve.
$$\frac {dx}{y}=\frac {dy}{x}$$
$$xdx=ydy $$
$$c_2=x^2-y^2$$
Is another integral curve.

So that the integral curves are:
$$
\begin{cases}
c_0=u \\
c_1=x+y-z \\
c_2=x^2-y^2 \\
\end{cases}
$$
Finally:
$$\boxed {u(x,y,z)=F(x+y-z,x^2-y^2)}$$